# Generate card_error in stripe.js while testing

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I dont know this can be done or not, but i was wondering is there any way to generate card_error on stripe for **testing**?

To clarify my question here's what I want to do:

- Stripe provides varieties of card numbers for testing purposes
  ([here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)). Along with this it also provides methods for form
  validation(eg. I enter 34/2013 as expiry date and i'll get invalid
  date error by validation then and there).
- But i want to create a situation where a
  user enters an expiry date which is a valid date (say 12/2015) but
  its not the real expiry date of the card, so that on sending this
  information to stripe, i recieve an error in json form named
  card_error. ([here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors))

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry, turned out to be stripe already has special codes for this purpose. I over looked that part of the page despite going through the page several times.. stupid me! :-/

Anyways here are the codes:
[image]

source: https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Comment: I've found that this won't work with stripe.js. It'll give you a valid token and then it'll fail on the server. So the fails work, but stripe.js will not pass back an error in testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take to this.

You pass the stripe API call a callback function. This callback is the unit of code that you want to test with the `card_error` type of response

```
'test card_error is handled correctly': function() {
    var response = {
        type: 'card_error',
        message: 'The human readable message',
        code: 'invalid_cvc'

    myStripeCallback(response)

    // Make assertions down here about what happened when 
    // you called the function with the error message
    // Maybe it emailed you, maybe it displayed a message
    // to the user. I would then probably make another test
    // for each `code` that I cared about.
}
```

The second approach would be to mock out the stripe api call entirely. Check that it was called with the right arguments and then call the provided callback with the error response that you wanted to deal with in that test.